# Insert from file - PowerPoint formatting

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Good morning and thanks for however can assist.

I have been running the Macro below for a while now and it works beautifully for combining the presentations.  However, it always converts all the slides into the Theme and Design of the main presentation and I would like to keep the formatting from the original slide.

Is there code to keep that original formatting??

Thanks again.

---

Sub InsertAllSlides()
'  Insert all slides from all presentations in the same folder as this one
'  INTO this one; do not attempt to insert THIS file into itself, though.

```
Dim vArray() As String
Dim x As Long

' Change "*.PPT" to "*.PPTX" or whatever if necessary:
EnumerateFiles ActivePresentation.Path & "\", "*.PPTX", vArray

With ActivePresentation
    For x = 1 To UBound(vArray)
        If Len(vArray(x)) > 0 Then
            .Slides.InsertFromFile vArray(x), .Slides.Count
        End If
    Next
End With
```

End Sub

Sub EnumerateFiles(ByVal sDirectory As String, _
    ByVal sFileSpec As String, _
    ByRef vArray As Variant)
    ' collect all files matching the file spec into vArray, an array of strings

```
Dim sTemp As String
ReDim vArray(1 To 1)

sTemp = Dir$(sDirectory & sFileSpec)
Do While Len(sTemp) > 0
    ' NOT the "mother ship" ... current presentation
    If sTemp <> ActivePresentation.Name Then
        ReDim Preserve vArray(1 To UBound(vArray) + 1)
        vArray(UBound(vArray)) = sDirectory & sTemp
    End If
    sTemp = Dir$
Loop
```

End Sub

Answer (score 4):

InsertFromFile doesn't offer much control over formatting (none, actually).

Instead, try the method offered at the bottom of this page:
https://software-solutions-online.com/copy-slides-one-presentation-another-vba-powerpoint/

In short:

```
Sub Example2()
Dim objPresentation As Presentation
Dim i As Integer

'open the target presentation
Set objPresentation = Presentations.Open("C:\2.pptx")
For i = 1 To objPresentation.Slides.Count
    objPresentation.Slides.Item(i).Copy
    Presentations.Item(1).Slides.Paste
    Presentations.Item(1).Slides.Item(Presentations.Item(1).Slides.Count).Design = _
        objPresentation.Slides.Item(i).Design
Next i
objPresentation.Close
End Sub
```

To avoid screen flickering and speed things up, you can use this instead of the above to open the presentation windowlessly:

```
Set objPresentation = Presentations.Open("C:\2.pptx"),,False
```